# How do I get the same queue into differnet multiprocessing files?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue

I see a lot of tutorials on how to use queues, but they always show them implemented in the same file. I'm trying to organize my code files well from the beginning because I anticipate the project to become very large. How do I get the queue that I initialize in my main file to import into the other function files?

Here is my main file:

```
import multiprocessing
import queue
from data_handler import data_handler
from get_info import get_memory_info
from get_info import get_cpu_info


if __name__ == '__main__':

    q = queue.Queue()

    getDataHandlerProcess = multiprocessing.Process(target=data_handler(q))
    getMemoryInfoProcess = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_memory_info(q))
    getCPUInfoProcess = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_cpu_info(q))

    getDataHandlerProcess.start()
    getMemoryInfoProcess.start()
    getCPUInfoProcess.start()

    print("DEBUG: All tasks successfully started.")
```

Here is my producer:

```
import psutil
import struct
import time
from data_frame import build_frame


def get_cpu_info(q):
    while True:
        cpu_string_data = bytes('', 'utf-8')
        cpu_times = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=0.0, percpu=True)
        for item in cpu_times:
            cpu_string_data = cpu_string_data + struct.pack('<d',item)
        cpu_frame = build_frame(cpu_string_data, 0, 0, -1, -1)
        q.put(cpu_frame)
        print(cpu_frame)
        time.sleep(1.000)


def get_memory_info(q):
    while True:
        memory_string_data = bytes('', 'utf-8')
        virtual_memory = psutil.virtual_memory()
        swap_memory = psutil.swap_memory()
        memory_info = list(virtual_memory+swap_memory)
        for item in memory_info:
            memory_string_data = memory_string_data + struct.pack('<d',item)
        memory_frame = build_frame(memory_string_data, 0, 1, -1, -1)
        q.put(memory_frame)
        print(memory_frame)
        time.sleep(1.000)


def get_disk_info(q):
    while True:
        disk_usage = psutil.disk_usage("/")
        disk_io_counters = psutil.disk_io_counters()
        time.sleep(1.000)
        print(disk_usage)
        print(disk_io_counters)


def get_network_info(q):
    while True:
        net_io_counters = psutil.net_io_counters()
        time.sleep(1.000)
        print(net_io_counters)
```

And here is my consumer:

```
def data_handler(q):
    while True:
        next_element = q.get()
        print(next_element)
        print('Item received at data handler queue.')
```

Comment: abstract producers and consumers into libraries, then import them into one file? it's very difficult to share a queue (though not impossible) with a process that is not a child or sibling of a single parent process. It seems you've already done that though, so I don't really understand the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear to me what do you mean by " How do I get the queue that I initialize in my main file to import into the other function files?".
Normally you pass a queue as and argument to a function and use it within a function scope regardless of the file structure. Or perform any other variable sharing techniques used for any other data type.

Your code seems to have a few errors however. Firstly, you shouldn't be using `queue.Queue` with `multiprocessing`. It has it's own version of that class.

```
q = multiprocessing.Queue()
```

It is slower than the `queue.Queue`, but it works for sharing the data across processes.

Secondly, the proper way to create process objects is:

```
getDataHandlerProcess = multiprocessing.Process(target=data_handler, args = (q,))
```

Otherwise you are actually calling `data_handler(q)` the main thread and trying to assign its return value to the `target` argument of `multiprocessing.Process`. Your `data_handler` function never returns, so the program probably gets into an infinite a deadlock at this point before multiprocessing even begins. Edit: actually it probably goes into infinite wait trying to get an element from an empty queue which will never be filled.

Comment: Your suggestions worked perfectly, thanks! The issue was that I was not using the .Process() function correctly. Adding the args made it stat the process correctly. Thanks!